# custom data-attribute in asp.net Linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

can i use custom attributes with linkbutton?

like this:

```
var linkb= new LinkButton();
linkb.ID = "myLinkButton";
linkb.Text = "x";
linkb.Click += linkbuttonClicked;
linkb.Attributes["data-id"] = "DataId";
linkb.CssClass = "lb";
MyPanel.Controls.Add(linkb);
```

Can i do something like this onClick?

```
var thisButton= (LinkButton) sender;
var test = thisButton.Attributes["data-id"]);
```

Comment: Why don't you actually simply try it and see what happens ?

Comment: I actually simply tried it and i could not get it to work! Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I was not contributing, I was just suggesting... Very often people ask before even trying and your question did not indicate you tried already, just if it was possible. I hope you'll find the answer to your problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can do that in ASP.NET 4.0, the attribute and value will be saved in the viewstate and persist across postbacks.

But, as it persists only in the viewstate, if you change its value client-side with some js/jquery, the new value will not be sent to the server on postback and will not persist.

Comment: That should be the case if i change or add the data-id attribute on the client side also?

Comment: If you create the attribute or change its value client-side only, it won't be posted to the server and will be lost.